magento 2 Can i change this H2 to H1
Can i change h2 to h1 on page title


In the default Magento theme, the file responsible for modifying the HTML title content is title.phtml.
In your case, it seems you were using the custom Theme so the path will be
app/design/your_vendor/your_theme/Magento_Theme/frontend/templates/html/title.phtml.
If the file not exist copy from the parent theme and create in your theme.
Make the necessary changes in the file - h2 tag to h1.

To change the page title from an H2 tag to an H1 tag across various pages in Magento 2, you can manage this through the title.phtml file in your custom theme. Below is a detailed guide on how to achieve this, ensuring that the changes are applied universally across your Magento site.
Steps to Change the Page Title from H2 to H1 in title.phtml
1. Locate or Create Your Custom Theme
If you already have a custom theme, skip to the next step. If not, you'll need to create one.

Create Your Theme Directory Structure:
app/design/frontend/YourVendor/YourTheme/


Create theme.xml:
This file defines your theme.
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Theme/etc/theme.xsd">
    <title>Your Theme Title</title>
    <parent>Magento/blank</parent> <!-- or Magento/luma -->
</theme>


Create registration.php:
This file registers your theme with Magento.
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
    'frontend/YourVendor/YourTheme',
    __DIR__
);



2. Copy the Default title.phtml File
The default title.phtml file is located in the following path:
vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/title.phtml

To copy it to your custom theme:

Create the Necessary Directory Structure:
mkdir -p app/design/frontend/YourVendor/YourTheme/Magento_Theme/templates/html/


Copy the title.phtml File:
cp vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/title.phtml app/design/frontend/YourVendor/YourTheme/Magento_Theme/templates/html/title.phtml



3. Edit the Copied title.phtml File
Now, edit the copied title.phtml file in your custom theme:
<?php
/** @var \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template $block */
?>
<h1 class="page-title">
    <?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getPageTitle()) ?>
</h1>

Explanation of Changes

H1 Tag: The line that originally used the H2 tag is now using an H1 tag, ensuring that your page titles are displayed correctly in an H1 format.

4. Clear Cache
After making your changes, it’s essential to clear the Magento cache to ensure that your updates are reflected on the frontend.
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush

5. Verify Your Changes

Navigate to different pages of your Magento store to verify that the titles are now rendered as H1 tags.

Summary
By following these steps, you have successfully changed the page title from H2 to H1 in Magento 2 through the title.phtml file in your custom theme. This will ensure that the page titles across the site are more SEO-friendly, as H1 tags are typically given more weight by search engines.
If you require further modifications or adjustments for specific page types, you can repeat similar processes for other title-related templates, ensuring your customizations align with your site's needs.
